# No space left on disk (PostgreSQL)

Tags: linux, logs, memory, postgresql, database

I was trying to write a 55GB SQL file to my database. It used to crash each time. I removed logs and did some cleaning to get the server running, but the transaction never used to complete. Latter, I emptied all the tables I was writing into (I had a backup), but even after that, when I tried writing the SQL file, it gave me this error after a series of successful inserts -  Could not write to file "pg_subtrans/14C6" at offset 106496: No space left on device.

Is there a way out of this? Are there logs related to PGSQL that I should still clean? I've read that moving the pg_xlog might just help? Should I try this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Output of `df -h` reformatted from comment for readability.

```
Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_zarkin-lv_root   574G  540G 4.3G  100% /
/dev/sda1                       194M  35M  150M  19%  /boot
tmpfs                           5.9G  928K 5.9G  1%   /dev/shm
/dev/mapper/smeidc0-smeisky0    7.2T  5.2T 2.0T  73%  /smeidc/sky0
/dev/md0                        7.2T  6.5T 400G  95%  /smeidc/backup
```

Comment: Have you tried breaking the import into more manageable pieces?

Comment: @DopeGhoti - Yeah, I divided into 12 files each of a size around 5GB. Should I make them smaller?

Comment: Output of `df -h` would likely be helpful here... Also indicate where your PGSQL data files are if they are not in the typical default location of `/var/lib/pgsql`.

Comment: One should also note that there is not a one-to-one correlation between the size of the SQL file and the amount of disk space that will be consumed by loading it. Depending on _many_ factors, the space used in the database could be larger or smaller than the size of the SQL file. Sometimes this difference can be quite large.

Comment: @Deathgrip- Hey, they are at the default location - /var/lib/pgsql. Can I remove the logs (pg_xlog) to get more space? Otherwise it gives me the No space left error.

Comment: @Deathgrip Also, the very first error that I get is this - ERROR:  could not extend relation 1663/16385/51434: No space left on device
 The output of df -h is :

Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_zarkin-lv_root  574G  540G  4.3G 100% /
/dev/sda1             194M   35M  150M  19% /boot
tmpfs                 5.9G  928K  5.9G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/mapper/smeidc0-smeisky0 7.2T  5.2T  2.0T  73% /smeidc/sky0
/dev/md0              7.2T  6.5T  400G  95% /smeidc/backup

Comment: Will it help if I backup my database, then manually remove files from var/lib/pgsql/data/base, and then restore the database?

Comment: You really need to find out where the space is being used before assuming it is the PGSQL logs. A command I like to use in my day job is `du -xk / | sort -n | tail -20` (change `/` to the base of the filesystem that is being checked). Without knowing how much space the logs are consuming, you won't know if purging them will help.

Answer (score 1):

> I was trying to write a 55GB SQL file to my database.
> [...] No space left on device.
> Is there a way out of this?

No.

Before loading, you should provide data volume sufficient for your application.

I know this answer is a little terse, so adding some newbie-level hints below.

#### Where does my disk space go?

Total disk space used by any postgres table is a consequence of physical model and consists of:

- Table blocks which contain table rows
- Index blocks (if you have indexes)
- Transaction logs (aka WAL, or xlog, which go away after some time)

Physical size of a table row depends on data types, how well the data compresses. There's approx. 22 bytes overhead for each row so if you have ~ 100 bytes of raw compressed data, your row will occupy ~ 122 bytes.

Physical size of indexes is even harder to predict, it depends on indexed fields, and index types.

#### Ho do I cut disk usage during bulk updates?

To minimize disk overhead, follow the official performance tips from PostgreSQL docs:

- [Non-Durable Settings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/non-durability.html)
- [Populating a Database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/populate.html)

#### How do I cut disk usage after bulk updates?

Here are some things to know which can help shrink database size in PostgreSQL:

- If you want to purge whole tables, be aware that SQL [`DELETE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-delete.html) does not always clean the files. Use [`TRUNCATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-truncate.html), not `DELETE` to remove table contents completely.
- If you canot purge the table completely, and you need to remove a large subset of rows (50% or more), it is very useful to run [`VACUUM FULL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-vacuum.html) or  [`CLUSTER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-cluster.html) command after DELETE, to shrink the table.
- Amount of data reserved for transaction logs (pg_xlog directory) can be controlled with [postgres server settings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-wal.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-WAL-CHECKPOINTS)
- Unused databases, tables and indexes can be detected with help of [system views](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-VIEWS) (pg_stat_database, pg_stat_user_tables, pg_stat_user_indexes)

Comment: It sounds like OP is trying to Import data into the DB. Your suggestions  are of no use until that operation has succeeded.

Comment: @mickeyfagain-beforeexitofso right. fixed

Comment: In a nutshell: if the data files of the database will be at the default location of `/var/lib/pgsql`, and there is currently only 4.3G of free space on that filesystem, the import of a 55GB SQL file is sure to fail. The actual data in the SQL file *might* take less than 55 GB in the database file form, but depending of the SQL file contents and DB configuration, the import may produce additional indexes which will also take up disk space, and/or another ~55GB of database transaction logs for online backup purposes. If import attempt fails, purging the database won't purge the logs.